# Problems keeping orthographic projection proportional using Qt/OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl, orthographic

I am having a difficult time understanding what values I should use in the call I make to QMatrix4x4::ortho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far).

Specifically, I don't understand the documentation for the values for left,right,bottom, and top.  I have a working demo that can draw the OpenGL monkey with a projection matrix.  I set up the demo so that when I hit 'O' on the keyboard, it switches the projection matrix from perspective to orthographic.  The perspective projection works well in that it keeps the model's aspect ratio constant (i.e. it doesn't stretch in width or height).  Here's the function that gets called when either the 'O' or 'P' key gets called and updates m_proj.  It's a bit of a hot mess as you can see I've tried a bunch of ideas and none of them really works the way I would like.

Thanks for any insight that would help me understand this.  Other helpful details: my view eye is at z=2 facing center (0,0,0) with up being (0,1,0).

```
void AppGLScene::setProjectionMatrix(void)
{
    m_projectionMatrix.setToIdentity();
    float windowWidth = rect().width();
    float windowHeight = rect().height();
    float left, right, bottom, top;
    float aratio = (float) windowWidth / (float) windowHeight;
    qDebug() << "win wid, win hei" << windowWidth << windowHeight;

    // I modify the vertical FOV in an attempt to keep the size of the
    // model the same as the vertical size of the window changes.
    //
    float vFov = 90 * ((float)windowHeight / m_initialWinHeight);
    qDebug() << "vFov" << vFov;

    switch (m_proj)
    {
    case PROJ_PERSP:
        m_projectionMatrix.perspective(vFov, qreal(windowWidth)/qreal(windowHeight), 0.5, 40);
        break;
    case PROJ_ORTHO:
    default:
//        left = rect().x();
//        right = rect().x() + rect().width();
//        bottom = rect().y();
//        top = rect().y() + rect().height();
        if (windowWidth > windowHeight)
        {
            left = -(3.0 - ((float)windowHeight/(float)windowWidth));
            right = -left;
            bottom = -3.0;
            top = 3.0;
        }
        else
        {
            left = -3.0;
            right = 3.0;
            bottom = -(3.0 - ((float)windowWidth/(float)windowHeight));
            top = -bottom;
        }

        qDebug() << "l r b t = " << left << right << bottom << top;
        m_projectionMatrix.ortho(left, right, bottom, top, 0.5, 40);
//        m_projectionMatrix.ortho(-3.0, 3.0, -3.0, 3.0, 0.5, 40);
//        m_projectionMatrix.ortho(-aratio, aratio, -aratio, aratio, 0.5, 40);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid stretching your objects in either direction, you need to have *(right - left) / (top - bottom)* match the aspect ratio of the window. Which in your case you can ensure by having *right* be the value of *top* multiplied by the aspect ratio.

It looks like you want to use the range [-3.0, 3.0] for the shorter window dimension, and adjust the longer one accordingly. The above then translates into:

```
    if (windowWidth > windowHeight)
    {
        top = 3.0f;
        bottom = -top;
        right = top * aratio;
        left = -right;
    }
    else
    {
        right = 3.0f;
        left = -right;
        top = right / aratio;
        bottom = -top;
    }
```

Note that *right / top = aratio* for both cases.

Comment: Reto - thanks for answering.  Your response does clear it up.  I tested and can keep the original width/height proportions of my model this way.  I will consider the question answered.  Now I will likely play with figuring out what the starting values (i.e. the 3.0) should be to make the orthographic-projected image look roughly the same size as the perspective-projected image.  I've been reading through the OpenGL Programming Guide, but they have their own code that they use in the book (vmath.h,.cpp), that takes an eye, center, and up to do the orthographic matrix multiply.

Comment: You can't make an ortho projection to look "roughly the same size as the perspective-projected image". You can make look similiar for any plane parallel to the image plane at a chosen distance from the camera.